# Nielsen & Chuang, exercise 10.2 — on the bit flip channel

Tags: computational-mathematics, quantum-computation, quantum-information

The question from Nielsen & Chuang's [Quantum Computation and Quantum Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Computation_and_Quantum_Information) asks to show that the action of the bit flip channel described by the quantum operation $$\epsilon(\rho)= (1 - p) \rho + p X\rho X$$
can be given an alternative operator-sum representation as:
$$\epsilon (\rho) = (1-2p)\rho + 2p P_{+} \rho P_{+} + 2p P_{-} \rho P_{-} $$

where $P_{+}$ and $P_{-}$ are projectors onto the $+1$ and $-1$ eigenstates of $X$.

It is my understanding that $p$ denotes the probability of a bit flip and $(1-p)$ denotes the probability of the state remaining unchanged.

From different sources, it seems that the first line of the proof involves rewriting $\epsilon (\rho)$ as $$\epsilon (\rho) = (1-2p) \rho + p (X\rho X + I \rho I)$$

I can take the proof from there but I don't understand how we reached this first line of the proof. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does $P$ stand for here? Did you mean to write $(1-2p)\rho$?

Comment: Yes, apologies that was supposed to be lower case p, the probability that the state undergoes a bit flip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $1-p=1-2p+p$, using some algebraic manipulation, we have

\begin{align}
\epsilon(\rho) &= (1-p)\rho + p X \rho X\\
&=(1-2p+p)\rho + pX \rho X \\
&= ( 1-2p)\rho + p\rho + pX \rho X \\
&=(1-2p)\rho + p(\rho + X\rho X)\\
&=(1-2p)\rho + p(I\rho I+X\rho X)
\end{align}

Note that $I$ is the identity here.